# JAVA Linked List Search Linked List to compare data with user inputted data?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a linked list. Everything is going great inside of it. My only problem is how do I compare a variable to the contents to see if their is a match.

For instance I have a linked list full of names. I want the user to be able to enter a name in and search to see if that name exists in the Linked List.

User enters: Johnny

Program checks if Johnny is present in Linked List.

I don't have the code for this as I am not sure of what it would be.

```
public static LinkedList<String> NameList1 = new LinkedList<String>(); // How do I search its contents?
```

THANKS SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `contains()` method in the `List` interface.

```
if (NameList1.contains("Johnny")) {
    // code to execute if Johnny is in the list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Collections class.  Within it is the goodness of the binarySearch method.  Follow the instructions for that method (create a Comparator or implement various methods on your class, etc.)  It'd be faster if you were using a random access list implementation, but it'll work.

Comment: binary search on a linked list is slower than  linear search at least half of the time!

Comment: Yep, mentioned that in my comment.